# Gradle - Could not find method artifactory() for arguments at init.gradle

Tags: java, gradle

**Specs version:**

- Java : 1.8.0_333
- Gradle : Gradle 7.4.2

**I'm always got this error**

```
* What went wrong: Could not find method artifactory() for arguments [init_dma9eorkjulwy6d24gkunp9js$_run_closure1$_closure7@77cf9353] on project ':buildSrc' of type org.gradle.api.Project.enter code here

* Exception is: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method artifactory() for arguments [init_dma9eorkjulwy6d24gkunp9js$_run_closure1$_closure7@77cf9353] on project ':buildSrc' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.methodMissingException(AbstractDynamicObject.java:182)
at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.ConfigureDelegate.invokeMethod(ConfigureDelegate.java:86)
at init_dma9eorkjulwy6d24gkunp9js$_run_closure1.doCall
```

**Already try using different java versions**: jdk12, jdk13, jdk14. Unfortunately, still got the same issue. Any suggestion solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I just realized, I need to update my gradle version also on my repo at this file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the right answer is - you forgot to apply your jfrog plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
```